# Long running workflow versioning: where and how to use OnActivityExecutionContextLoad?

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4

We have a long running workflow which uses SQL tracking service (.Net WF 4.0). In the next update, we would like to introuduce a public property in one of the arguments of the workflow. Since this is breaking change, the persisted workflow inatances throw the following error on re-loading:

```
System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.InstancePersistenceCommandException: The execution of the InstancePersistenceCommand named .. LoadWorkflow was interrupted by an error.

InnerException: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: 'Element' '_x003C_BookmarkName_x003E_k__BackingField' from namespace '...' is not expected. Expecting element '....'
```

I understand this is a typical versioning issue and one of the recommendations I noticed on some of the sites is to override *OnActivityExecutionContextLoad* method and fill in the missing values. But I am not sure where and how to do this! OnActivityExecutionContextLoad is declared in *System.Workflow.ComponentModel.Activity* (.Net 3.5?) whereas what we have is a code-based top-level custom activity derived from *System.Activities.NativeActivity* (which receives the argument in question). Can something be done in this class to initialize the missing property of the argument?

All suggestions are welcome :)